# SQL : Creating a trigger and having a compilation error on bash screen

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, syntax, triggers

I've been trying to set my trigger script (in PostgreSQL) and i always obtain an error message like this one :

```
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

Here is the script code in question :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CityExists
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Player
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        WHEN (NOT EXISTS( SELECT idTeam FROM Team WHERE Team.idTeam = NEW.idTeam)) THEN 
            signal sqlstate '45000' 
                set message_text = 'Attempt to insert a player with an non-existing city.';
        END
    END
```

Actually i can't find my error, am i missing something here ?

Comment: You've written PostgreSQL and tagged your question Oracle. Which is it?

Comment: Oracle

Found out what was wrong.

The NEW. needs to be written like this :NEW

And the signal sqlstate doesnt work

I used instead RAISE_EXCEPTION